# Accessing and updating a custom section in a config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a config file which has a custom section added to it. How do I access the `ConnectionString` field and update it? (I can't use xpath or any xml related stuff)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>   
        <section name="HandleApplication" 
                 type="Contracts.ConfigSections.HandleApplication, Contracts"/>
    </configSections>
    <HandleApplication>
        <Handler  AppId="2" ConnectionString="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>    
    </HandleApplication>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use any xml related stuff?
You might wanna consider [REGEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why would you use regex to read well defined configuration file?

Comment: @Haim I can only use methods from ConfigurationManager, pls don't ask why :)

Comment: @user1890098 Why?

Comment: @mason I'm full aware to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).
but he specifically said that he can't use any XML related stuff.

user1890098 you can enumerate through all the properties of the configuaration. if you tell me what properties are dynamic and what not I could give you a working code example